# Calculate the Response time for REST API request in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I am newbie to python and Django RESTAPI , can anyone suggest how to calculate the response time for rest api request (of all method types).

Comment: That's going to be hard and depending on so many factors that I'd say it's impossible. You'd have to benchmark.

Comment: using timeit module in python , it can be achievable ah?

Answer (score 1):

[django-silk](https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk) is an excellent package that will show you the actual request/response time for API calls

In addition to showing basic numbers, you can see the SQL query itself that was executed for that call as well as profiling information.

Comment: I don't want to change in api viewset  and wants to handle in testcase to calculate the response time while calling the api and passing the values in it.please help me

Comment: Lots of extra work, for what reason? Is this really going to be a beneficial thing?

Answer (score 0):

Read the article below which is written by @tomchrist DRF developer. He explained it very well.
https://www.dabapps.com/blog/api-performance-profiling-django-rest-framework/

Comment: Could you add at least a few points of the mentioned source in your answer?